# ¿Cómo puedo agrupar guardas en Haskell?

Tags: programación-funcional, haskell

Al igual que podemos **agrupar condicionales en lenguajes imperativos**:

```
if(condicion) then 
  if(condicion) then accion
  else accion
else accion
```

**¿podemos agrupar guardas en Haskell?** Lo he intentado, pero me devuelve un **error de parser** en el símbolo "|" de la segunda guarda (línea dos del pseudocódigo):

```
| condicion
  | condicion accion
  | condicion accion
| otherwise accion
```

He probado a escribir "=" antes del agrupamiento (por si se diera el caso):

```
| condicion =
  | condicion accion
  | condicion accion
| otherwise accion
```

Pero tampoco. ¿Pueden ayudarme? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es posible *"anidar"* salvaguardas. Todas las salvaguardas tiene que estar referidas a una expresión lógica:

```hs
 | condicion1 = accion1
 | condicion2 = accion2
 | otherwise  = accion3
```

Aquí `otherwise` se usa por claridad, pero no deja de ser un alias de `true` para que funcione como caso por defecto.

Para lo que pides, habría que especializar la expresión de salvaguarda:

```hs
 | condicion1 && condicion_extra = accion1_extra1
 | condicion1 && not condicion_extra = accion1_extra2
 | condicion2 = accion2
 | otherwise  = accion3
```

Como las salvaguardas se evaluan en orden, se puede evitar evaluar la expresión negativa:

```hs
 | condicion1 && condicion_extra = accion1_extra1
 | condicion1 = accion1_extra2
 | condicion2 = accion2
 | otherwise  = accion3
```

De todos modos, siempre se podría haber usado una sentencia `if..then` o  `case..of` para hacer lo mismo, todo depende de lo complejas que sean las expresiones:

```hs
 | condicion1 = if condicion_extra then accion1_extra1 else accion1_extra2
 | condicion2 = accion2
 | otherwise  = accion3
```

O también, emplear una expresión auxiliar:

```hs
 | condicion1 = accion1'
 | condicion2 = accion2
 | otherwise  = accion3

   where accion1' | condicion_extra = accion1_extra1
                  | otherwise = accion1_extra2
```